# Double Commander custom actions configuration

Tags: file-management, xubuntu

I need some help to set custom actions in Double Commander.

For example: I set an action to open directory as root but when I select this option in the context menu (left click on selected directory) and hit it nothing happens. What am I missing in the configuration ?

I attached screenshot of this configuration.

[image]

Other issue : selected .docx file then hit enter opens Viewer app from Xubuntu to send an email, but hitting .doc file opens LibreOffice-Writer (it's expected).

[image]

How to solve these issues?

Comment: `left click on selected directory` - what do you mean? - and `selected .docx file then hit enter `?

Answer (score 2):

Some details are obscure to me in this question. The OP asks about **actions**, and the screenshot clearly shows what this is about. But it seems that the OP expects the actions to appear by  `left click on selected directory` and  by `selecting .docx file then hitting enter`.

Actions are supposed to appear under ***Actions*** within the menu triggered by **right-click**:

[image]

I understand that one demand is how to open a folder as root. It is not clear what are the other demands. One seems to be opening a text as root. There are some doc files involved but it is not clear what action is intended for those.

---

Anyway:

### Open Folder as root in Double Commander:

Command: `pkexec`

Parameters: `env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY doublecmd %p`

[image]

### Opening text as root

While `folder` seems to work as "extension" for folders, I don't know what "extension" to enter for Linux text files that do not have an explicit extension (e.g. `txt`), which makes this kind of action a bit useless, given that on Linux not all root files have a such extension (and the Double Commander doesn't seem to include a *mimetype* entry in those actions settings). — A workaround is to open a folder as root in the file manager and open the file from there.

For `txt` extension (or others, like `sh` or `desktop`):

Command: `pkexec`

Parameters: `env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY <TEXT_EDITOR> %p`